# 「。。。であるのも」は「であるし」の意味ですか？

Tags: grammar

> 朝の時間が、思考にとって黄金の時間**であるのも**、頭の工場の中がよく整頓されて、動きやすくなっているからにほかならない。

外山さんの「思考の整理学」から。

タイトルの通りに、ここの「であるのも」は「であるし」のかたい言い方ですか？後、この「であるのも」の「の」は説明する意味ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

その「の」は、 nominalizer です。「朝の時間が思考にとって黄金の時間である」を名詞句の形に変えて、主語として使えるようにしています。

わかりやすくするために、埋め込まれた文にカッコを補うと、

> 『朝の時間が、思考にとって黄金の時間である』のも、『頭の工場の中がよく整頓されて、動きやすくなっている』からにほかならない。

全体の文は、

> ［文A］のも、［文B］からにほかならない。

という形で、

> ［文A］のは(も)、まさに［文B］からだ。
>   "The reason for [Sentence A] is nothing other than [Sentence B]."
>   "It is only because [Sentence B] that [Sentence A]."

というような意味です。少し補って、

> 『朝の時間が思考にとって黄金の時間である』というのも、まさに『頭の工場の中がよく整頓されて動きやすくなっている』｛からです。/ ということが理由です。｝

のように言い換えることもできます。